# How to add extra custom attributes in Linkit Profiles?

Tags: 8, nodes

I need to add my custom attribute in Linkit profile.

[image]

For eg. I have a linkit module and I want to add my custom attribute called 'Ajax attribute' in /admin/config/content/linkit/manage/default_linkit/attributes/add
So, I can open my ajax model in an overlay, frame, etc.

How can I achieve this scenario, Any leads?

Comment: You'll need to write your own Attribute plugin which extends `Drupal\linkit\AttributeBase`. You can use the existing plugins under `Drupal\linkit\Plugin\Linkit\Attribute` for inspiration

Comment: @Clive - But, if I want to create a custom module with the dependency of Linkit module, it doesn't work. What I miss it? I simply create info and under \src\Plugin\Linkit\Attribute, attribute file.

Comment: Attributes have been removed from 5.x and onward in favor of [editor_advanced_link](https://www.drupal.org/project/editor_advanced_link).